# Replacing a legacy model with a new one of the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Re-structuring a legacy app I wanted to re-use one of the model names because it is too perfect not to.

I want to make it totally invisible to the outside, JSON API, preferably even the controller layer, that these models do not have the default table name. But I cannot figure out the final puzzle piece. aliasing the foreign keys without making a chain and breaking it all.

So I have two tables. The old table `perfections` which I will be migrating away from, but not in one go unfortunately. Then the new table `imperfections` which will be taking over.

I can easily mask the table names:

```
class Perfection < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "imperfections"
end
class LegacyPerfection < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "perfections"
end
```

Models holding a foreign key to these though. That is my problem. In fact I have one problem model. It belongs to both these models. I can alias only one of the foreign keys to look like what I want from the outside but aliasing both I get an alias chain because of the shared name.

```
class OtherThing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :perfection, foreign_key: :imperfection_id
  belongs_to :legacy_perfection, foreign_key: :perfection_id, optional: true
  alias_attribute :legacy_perfection_id, 'perfection_id'
  alias_attribute :perfection_id, 'imperfection_id'
end
```

I totally see why this makes an alias chain. The aliases are effectively doing the equivalent to this (and more for the getters snd stuff)

```
class OtherThing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :perfection, foreign_key: :imperfection_id
  belongs_to :legacy_perfection, foreign_key: :perfection_id, optional: true

  def legacy_perfection_id=(value)
    self.perfection_id = value
  end
  def perfection_id=(value)
    self.imperfection_id = value
  end
end
```

If I call `other_thing.legacy_perfection_id = 1` this number will be saved into `imperfection_id`.

I wonder if I can do something else... like actually change the attribute names somehow, and end up with a model where the parameters you pass to create or update are not revealing the internals.

For now I will do the transformation in the controller but I would like to have it be even cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input parameters you pass to your model are not really linked to its attributes or columns - they are linked to setter methods. [`assign_attributes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/32709ea41ed1ec2a89590e9bc6656c1ecd462d30/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L66) basically just does:

```
attributes.each do |k, v|
  send("#{k}=", v)
end
```

So if you want the model to accept `new_attribute` as input but still assign the old attribute you can do it with:

```
def new_attribute=(value)
  self.old_attribute = value
end
```

In some cases though it can be useful to have adapters. Like if API v1 accepts `old_attribute` and API v2 accepts `new_attribute`. To keep the difference from leaking into the model layer you add an adapter that transforms the params before you assign them. This is actually a controller concern in MVC as the controller is responsible for accepting user input and passing it to models.

Comment: Thanks. That would work with some limitations, as I understand. There are ways of assigning/updating the model data that bypasses this setter, like write_attribute and update_all. This post had a nice visual table of the various attribute assignment options. https://davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/

Comment: `update_all` just creates a SQL update query so setters/attributes etc are irrelevant.